# Safari won't enter fullscreen

Tags: macos, safari, fullscreen

I'm currently running Safari 5.1.4 on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3, and after bringing it out of the fullscreen mode, I quit safari using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

When I restarted my Mac, for some reason, Safari won't return to fullscreen mode despite attempts to click on the icon on the upper right hand corner or by going through the *View* menu manually. ( I've also tried the short cut keys as well, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, to no avail).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is it just Safari? If not, is the Dock process running or do you have a Dock?

Comment: @Lauri: It's only Safari, all other apps are running as normal. The mail client is able to exit fullscreen and enter fullscreen as normal. To answer your question: I have a dock but doesn't it always run in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem by quitting safari and reopening it again. Once it's open, i just go into fullscreen mode again and it responded nicely.